# Class 'CakePdf\Pdf\CakePdf' not found

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, wkhtmltopdf

I am new in Cake php and i want to use wkhtmltopdf plugin but Class 'CakePdf\Pdf\CakePdf' not found message is shown

in Config/bootstrap.php I added the following:

```
Plugin::load('CakePdf', ['bootstrap' => true]);
Configure::write('CakePdf', [
'engine' => [
    'className' => 'CakePdf.WkHtmlToPdf',
    'binary' => __DIR__ . '/../plugins/wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
    'options' => [
        'print-media-type' => false,
        'outline' => true,
        'dpi' => 96
    ],
],]);
```

in my contoller class method is:

```
$pdf_path = WWW_ROOT . 'user_forms' . DS . $user_form['form_number'] . DS . date('Y-m-d') . DS . $user_form['tracking_id'] . '.pdf';
    $CakePdf = new \CakePdf\Pdf\CakePdf();
    $CakePdf->template('userform', 'ajax');
    $CakePdf->viewVars(array(
        'form_preview' => $user_form['form_preview'], 'tracking_id' => $this->enToBn($user_form['tracking_id'])
    ));
    $pdf = $CakePdf->output();
    $pdf = $CakePdf->write($pdf_path);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this at top of your controller:

```
App::uses('CakePdf', 'CakePdf.Pdf');
```

I think this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

You should `use CakePdf\Pdf\CakePdf;` at the top of you controller. This will bring in the CakePdf namespace.

Then change your fuction like so:

```
$pdf_path = WWW_ROOT . 'user_forms' . DS . $user_form['form_number'] . DS . date('Y-m-d') . DS . $user_form['tracking_id'] . '.pdf';
    $CakePdf = new CakePdf();
    $CakePdf->template('userform', 'ajax');
    $CakePdf->viewVars(array(
        'form_preview' => $user_form['form_preview'], 'tracking_id' => $this->enToBn($user_form['tracking_id'])
    ));
    $pdf = $CakePdf->output();
    $pdf = $CakePdf->write($pdf_path);
```

If you *need* to pull it in there then I think

`$CakePdf = new \CakePdf\Pdf\CakePdf\CakePdf();`

should do it.